# How do I read the comments on this questions? Notifications take my to question's URL and nothing there

Tags: support, bug, comments, notifications

I have a question about my Ask Different post: [Can anyone explain to me the difference between Terminal, CLI, CLT and Prompt?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400997/can-anyone-explain-to-me-the-difference-between-terminal-cli-clt-and-prompt)

I could see that someone requested a screenshot. When I clicked on that notification this is where it took me.[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you maybe add a screenshot of what you see when you click on the notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Inbox notifications for comments take you to the question page and scroll down the page to highlight the new comment.

When you’re already on the question page that the notification is for, only the scrolling needs to happen. There’s no page navigation which would refresh the page, so the page relies on being told about new comments and updating the page using WebSockets.

Occasionally these WebSockets can be disconnected and fail to reconnect, or be blocked by a firewall or ad blocker. Therefore, because the inbox notification doesn’t reload the page, and the page hasn’t updated itself to show the new comment, the notification appears to not link to anything since the comment it tries to scroll to and highlight doesn’t appear.

Refresh the page or navigate away and then select the inbox notification for the page to be loaded again completely, which will include the new comment or post that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

When opening the question (e.g. by clicking on the link in your post above) you should see something like

[image]